# Не работает for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал программу. Но не могу понять, почему не работает цикл for.

```
import math
import time
print('Программа работает с геометрической прогрессией')
time.sleep(2)
print('Прежде чем мы начнем, напишите, Вы знаете второй член прогрессии b2 (Да/Нет): ')
answer=input()
if answer == 'Да':
    print('Введите первый член прогрессии (!= 0): ') # а можно было так: b1 = input('текст')
    b1 = input()
    print('Введите второй член прогрессии (!= 0): ')
    b2 = input()
    q = eval(b2) / eval(b1)
elif answer == 'Нет':
    print('Введите первый член прогрессии (!= 0): ')
    b1 = input()
    print('Введите знаменатель прогрессии (!= 0, 1): ') # 1 исключая для формулы суммы
    q = input()
    b2 = eval(b1) * eval(q)
else:
    print('Ошибка ввода. Работа программы прекращена.')
    time.sleep(3)
    exit(0)


print()
print('Отлично. Теперь у нас есть всё, для того чтобы поработать с прогрессией!')
print('Bn: b1 = '+str(b1)+'; b2 = '+str(b2)+'; q = '+str(q))
print()
time.sleep(1)
print('Давайте найдем какой-нибудь член этой прогрессии.')
print('Введите номер члена (n), который будем искать: ')
n=input()
bn = float(b1) * (float(q) ** (int(n) - 1))
print()
print('Bn: b'+str(n)+' = '+str(bn))
print()
time.sleep(1)
print('Окей. А теперь найдем сумму n первых членов этой прогрессии.')
sn = (float(b1) * (float(q) ** (int(n))-1)) / (float(q) - 1)
print('Sn = '+str(sn))
nn = int(input('Введите количество элементов этой прогрессии, которое Вы хотите увидеть'))
for i in range(1, nn):
    b1 *= q
    print(f'b{i} = {b1}')
```

Ругается на последнюю строку: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Какая строка тут 44-я?

Comment: print(f'b{i} = {b1}')

Comment: Скорее всего вы используете версию Python, которая не поддерживает f-строки (они поддерживаются начиная с Python 3.6)

Comment: И что делать? Как изменить код так, чтобы он работал?

Comment: Шебанг укажите, например, соответствующий. Или запускайте правильной версией питона.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего вы используете версию Python, которая не поддерживает f-строки (они поддерживаются начиная с Python 3.6).

Решение:

1. Установить более новую версию Python (или запускать более новой версией, если она уже установлена), или
2. Использовать другие варианты форматирования строк, например:

   ```
   print('b{i} = {b1}'.format(i=i, b1=b1))
   ```

   или

   ```
   print('b{} = {}'.format(i, b1))
   ```

   или ("старый" Си-подобный стиль)

   ```
   print('b%d = %s' % (i, b1))
   ```